# runtime error 91 excel vba, Object not set

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

what is wrong with the following code?, Every time I run it I get a "Run-Time Error 91, Object variable or with black variable not set"

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

Dim workBook As workBook
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set workBook = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Credit_Check_DB.xls", True, True)
txtCompany1.Value = workBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Formula
txtCompany2.Value = workBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Formula
txtCityState1.Value = workBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Formula
txtCityState2.Value = workBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Formula
txtDate1.Value = workBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F1").Value
txtAddress1.Value = workBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Formula
txtZip1.Value = workBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D1").Formula
txtPO.Value = "Purchase Order#:    " & workBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I1").Formula
txtRec.Value = workBook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K1").Formula
workBook.Close False
Set workBook = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Close_Excel
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Close_Excel() 'closes excel application.

Dim Excel As Excel.Application
Dim ExcelOpened As Boolean

ExcelOpened = False
On Error Resume Next
Set Excel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Excel Is Nothing Then
    Set Excel = New Excel.Application
    ExcelOpened = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

With Excel
    If ExcelOpened Then
        .Visible = True
        .Workbooks.Add
    End If
    .ActiveWorkbook.Close False  ***<-***!!!!!Debugger points to here!!!!!******
    .Quit
End With

End Sub
```

any idea what is wrong with my code? I am basically pulling information from Excel into word.

Comment: Don't use reserved words for your variables `Dim Excel As Excel.Application` ! Change it to something like this: `Dim MyExcelApp As Excel.Application`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Excel` does not point to any Excel application (something went wrong, but you skipped the error), so `ActiveWorkbook` points to nothing. You should put `On Error GoTo 0` immediately after GetObject.